# Excel Formulas Find Sum of Abs Value of Differences

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in rows:

| EmployeeName | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | ... | Score 50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 100 | 85 | 55 | ... |  |
| Jane Smith | 80 | 70 | 60 | ... |  |

I want to take absolute value of each difference between rows, then add them all up. So:

```
100 - 80 = 20, 85 - 70 = 15, ABS(55-60) = 5. 20 + 15 + 5 = 40.
```

I started to manually type the formula out
`=SUM(ABS(B2-B3),ABS(C2-C3),...)`, but there has to be a more efficient way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(B2:D2-B3:D3))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Perhaps I should've foreseen my next question coming. I tried to add an Indirect to the formula and am getting a #VALUE error. See edits above.

Comment: @RickyDrennan do not edit the question with new conditions after getting an answer.  Instead ask a new question.

Comment: I understand. Will post new question after enough time lapses. Thanks!