# Using Indirect with SumProduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230865/excel-formulas-find-sum-of-abs-value-of-differences/67230961#67230961), I am trying to implement the `SUMPRODUCT(ABS())` formula to include an INDIRECT. The reason for this is that I want to run the calculation for each combination of employees. Row 2 now contains a list of all employees and column A contains the same list of all employees. I'm attempting the following formula in cell B3. I am getting a #VALUE error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(INDIRECT("Sheet1!J"&ROW(A3)-1&":BB"&ROW(A3)-1)-INDIRECT("Sheet1!J"&COLUMN(B2)&":BB"&COLUMN(B2))))
```

Comment: I do not get the error.  Is `Sheet1` the actual name you are using?

Comment: It wasn't. But I changed it to Sheet1 and the problem persists.

Comment: does your data have errors in them?  The formula should work as is.  But you can try changing the INDIRECT to `INDEX(Sheet1!J:BB,ROW(A3)-1,0)` and `INDEX(Sheet1!J:BB,COLUMN(B2),0)`

Comment: If that does not work try:`=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(N(INDEX(Sheet1!J:BB,ROW(A3)-1,0)-INDEX(Sheet1!J:BB,COLUMN(B2),0))))`

Comment: Also you may need to check the data to ensure there is no text or empty strings`""`.  If the subtraction fails it will cause the whole to fail.

Comment: Your `SUMPRODUCT(ABS(N(INDEX...))))` method works. Not sure what this means - but happy to have it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABS in older version outside Office 365 does not like to use arrays and as such we must "force" it to use arrays with `N()`.

Also avoid INDIRECT if possible as it is volatile and will cause calc slow down.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(N(INDEX(Sheet1!J:BB,ROW(A3)-1,0)-INDEX(Sheet1!J:BB,COLUMN(B2),0))))
```